# Simple audio equalizer design: One filter is sending all the other signals to ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, analog, filter, active-filter

I’m designing and building an audio equalizer with active frequency filters for my school project and I thought the base design was completely functional until I decided to simulate it on Proteus VSM.

Turns out the circuit output doesn’t correlate with I was expecting. Analysing the circuit cautiously I found out that any potentiometer affects all the other filters and sends all their signals to ground (Or that’s what it looks like).

**Circuit schematic:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

[image]

**Proteus VSM Screenshots (Blue signal is Output):**

**98% (Signal displays)**

[image]

**28% (Signal disappears)**

[image]

I don’t know if the base design I'm following is wrong or the simulation is showing a mistaken output. Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your pots pull current out of the common node for all. Either make things higher impedance or buffer each filters input.

Comment: I haven't got space for buffering all the inputs, what do you refer by making things higher impedance? Adding a resistor in series with every filter? Thanks for giving me a clue! @PlasmaHH

Comment: yeah, that could work too. get familiar with ac analysis in your tool to see better whats going on and if it filters the way you want

Comment: A gyrator filter works better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a virtual ground mixer on a single-ended supply circuit.

[image]

*Figure 1.*

1. The op-amp non-inverting input is biased to 6 V.
2. Therefore the output is biased to 6 V.
3. Moving the pot wiper will vary the voltage at (3) from 0 V DC to 6 V DC + the audio component.
4. Voltage at (4) will be rather messed up.

So you have two problems:

- You can't connect the bottoms of the pots to ground when there's DC on them.
- You can't feed ground-referenced signals into a single-supply virtual ground summing amplifier.

[image]

*Figure 2. Adding decoupling capacitors at (1) and (2) will remove the DC from the potentiometers and allow the virtual ground (IC2D pin 13) to operate at +6 V.*

Because you are using 1k potentiometers (on the low side) you'll need large capacitors at (1).

Comment: That would be 12 non-polarized electrolytic capacitors more! Should I switch my design to dual power supply in order to avoid this tricky design? Anyway, you did an awesome analysis and I must mark this as solved!

Comment: Why not use electrolytics? They would all have 6 V DC across them. I'm out of touch with current thinking on whether or not they cause any distortion but are used in professional mixers, etc. I was half expecting someone to comment that we could replace all the C(2)s with one big one at the summing point. I've never seen it done but suspect that if its impedance is low enough that it would work. If you don't need battery operation then split-rail operation seems like a good plan. You may still have a little offset on the op-amps giving some DC through the pots.

Comment: I’m using those because my professor said so, but I have used polarized electrolytic back then on a common emitter amplifier as a coupling and decoupling cap. and they were functional. The project is a not battery based, we are testing it on a laboratory with frequency generators, oscilloscopes, and many power supplies; So then I will consider switching my design to a dual power supply. Thanks again!